# Footer spacing inconsistency with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using the fancyhdr package with multiple columns. As you can see from the image bellow, the text spacing is inconsistent. I've tried to use `\footskip` in the geometry package and looking online, but it dosen't work either.

[image]

My multi-file code is messy, so I've made a [copy](https://sv.overleaf.com/6144321663mprdfjddpzyp) of the whole thing. Have a look in `stylelist` > `mystyle.sty` for relevant code. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `\color` command pushes the page number down. This seems like a bug in `fancyhdr` to me. One of my TODO items says that I must check the color handling in `fancyhdr`. Your example shows that it need to be reworked indeed.

For the time being you can solve the problem by changing `\color{oscars-darkblue}\thepage` to `\textcolor{oscars-darkblue}{\thepage}` in both places.

```
\fancyfoot[L]{{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\scriptsize\copyright{} Håkansson \& Hallberg (2022)}}
\fancyfoot[C]{{\bfseries\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\textcolor{oscars-darkblue}{\thepage}}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\scriptsize Gymnasiearbete (100p)}
```

Comment: This was solved in `fancyhdr` version `4.0.2`.